# No results in phpMyAdmin after adding a comment after semicolon

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, comments

I observed strange behavior in *phpMyAdmin* version: *4.4.15.10*...

This query is valid and returns one row:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

However, I was very surprised when I add any comment after the semicolon (`;`)  and I will not receive any result or any error message, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1; -- comment
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1;
-- comment
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1; /* comment */
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1;
/* comment */
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1; /* the
comment */
```

Removing the semicolon (`;`) at the end fixes this behavior (the query is returns one row correctly), but all this behavior is very non-intuitive and confusing, especially when working with several queries at once.

Can anyone give me a hint how easily changed (repaired) it e.g. by some configuration or in some other way?

I appreciate your help with this issue.

Comment: *"Removing the semicolon (;) at the end fixes this behavior (the query is returns one row correctly), but all this behavior is very non-intuitive and confusing, especially when working with several queries at once"* You have to know that PHP does not really support multiple SQL statements separated with semicon (`;`) within the most functions in the MySQLi and PDO libs..

Comment: So i think PHPAdmin does under the hood a explode on `;` and executes the SQL statements `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1` and `-- comment` separated within a loop.. Also that would explain you not getting a error as `-- comment` alone is [valid syntax](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eF4K6r2nABS9dtgZq4N2c/0) from MySQL's point of view

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think you can confidently give an answer :)